# Tomcat service not starting (Windows Server 2012)

Tags: tomcat, windows-services, tomcat8, windows-server-2012

I am currently working on deploying my application with Tomcat 8.0.47 on a Windows Server 2012 but for some reason my Tomcat service is not starting.

Here is what I did to create my service:

```
"D:\Tomcat 8.0 API_RECETTE\bin\tomcat8.exe" //IS//Tomcat_API_RECETTE --DisplayName="Apache Tomcat API_RECETTE" --Description="Apache Tomcat 8.0.47 Server - http://tomcat.apache.org/" --Startup="auto"
"D:\Tomcat 8.0 API_RECETTE\bin\tomcat8.exe" //US//Tomcat_API_RECETTE --Classpath="D:\Tomcat 8.0 API_RECETTE\bin\bootstrap.jar;D:\Tomcat 8.0 API_RECETTE\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
"D:\Tomcat 8.0 API_RECETTE\bin\tomcat8.exe" //US//Tomcat_API_RECETTE --Jvm="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll"
"D:\Tomcat 8.0 API_RECETTE\bin\tomcat8.exe" //US//Tomcat_API_RECETTE --StartClass="org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap" --StartMode="jvm" ++StartParams="start
"D:\Tomcat 8.0 API_RECETTE\bin\tomcat8.exe" //US//Tomcat_API_RECETTE --StopClass="org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap" --StopMode="jvm" ++StopParams="stop" --StopTimeout="0"
```

When I start the service, even the service's state is set tot "startup", but when I refresh the page, the service is actualy not started at all. I have no error message returned, so it is quite difficult to understand what is going on.

My question is : how can I make it start ?

Comment: Notice that Tomcat 8.0.x has seen its [end of life](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-80-eol.html) in June 2018. Also, stackoverflow is for questions about your own code, not for server maintenance and setup questions.

Comment: Are there any logs in D:\Tomcat 8.0 API_RECETTE\logs?

Comment: No, that's the problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out why it wasn't working. It turns out that another Tomcat service had been badly configured in parallel and was pointing to configuration files from this Tomcat.

So this indirectly linked the two Tomcats and as the other one was started, it was impossible to start my new Tomcat.

So I dissociated the two by reconfiguring everything correctly and the problem was solved.